# Create user in PostgreSQL sudo: unknown user

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, unix, psql

I'm trying to create a new user in PostgreSQL installed on Ubuntu 20.04:

```
$ sudo -u postgres createuser --superuser tommy
```

But when I try to create a database with that user it says unknown user:

```
$ sudo -u tommy createdb tommy_db
sudo: unknown user: tommy
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
```

The think is that I already know that there are UNIX users and PostgreSQL users and I don't know if I have to create first a UNIX user tommy or not.

I would like to take advantage of the post and ask what is the difference between a postgreSQL user and a UNIX user in postgreSQL in terms of database management.

**PD:** If I list the users using /du in plsql I can see the created user tommy:

```
 Role name |                         Attributes                         | Member of
-----------+------------------------------------------------------------+-----------
 tommy     | Superuser, Create role, Create DB                          | {}
 postgres  | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication, Bypass RLS | {}
```

Comment: You don't need a unix user at all.  Go in as a superuser and `create role tommy login password 'xyz' superuser`

Comment: "*what is the difference between a postgreSQL user and a UNIX user in postgreSQL*" - well one is to authenticate against the operating system, the other is needed to authenticate against the database. It's the same difference between your Linux user and the user account you used to log-in to Stackoverflow.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name of course I know that but why is there a user postgres in UNIX system?

Comment: It is used to run the service because it would be a security risk to run the Postgres service as `root`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your system is probably using simple "peer" authentication by default. That is a common default for Linux-based package managers to use when they create a database for you.

To keep using that set up, then you yes you will need to set up "tommy" as a Linux user.  Or, you will have to edit pg_hba.conf to pick a different method, like md5 (password) or gss (kerberos), or to add an ident map along with "peer" to describe which OS users are allowed to log in as which database users.

The only connection between the Linux user and the PostgreSQL user is the one created by the use of peer authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to be logged as a root user by using `sudo su` or `sudo -i`

So that's likely part of the problem - when you use `sudo -u postgres` from the root account, it's trying to access root's home directory as the non-root user postgres.

That should work pretty well.